# Question on the Proof about Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (part 2)

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a difficulty in understanding the proof of fundamental theorem of calculus (part 2):

$\int_a^bf(x)dx=F(b)-F(a)$

The proof says we know $F(x)=g(x)+C$ for $(a,b)$ (where $g(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$), but both $F$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, so if taking limits on both sides, we see $F(x)=g(x)+C$ also holds for $[a,b]$.

I still don't understand why this is true. If this is the case, why does this relation originally hold true only for the open internal instead of closed one? Can anyone give me any sort of intuition or explanation about this?

Comment: What is $g{}{}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I updated the question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suspicion of what's going:

Part one says that $\frac{d}{dx} g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$, where $g(x):=\int_a^x f(x)\,dx$. Thus, for any $C$, the function $F(x)=g(x)+C$ is also an antiderivative of $f(x)$ on $(a,b)$. The function $g(x)$ is continuous so therefore, so is $F(x)$. Bounded continuous functions can be extended to include the end points.